# How do I change my login screen on lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, login

I am fairly new to Linux and Ubuntu and I'm trying Lubuntu out for the first time, I would like to know step-by-step how I would change the look and layout of my login screen.  I've heard lightdm-gtk-greeter is a good way to go, but I can't get the settings manager to actually work, can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Which release are you using?   Lubuntu uses `sddm` in its two most recent releases, but .....  (ie. *you'll have to provide us with mor,e for useful advice for you as we don't currently know your release, thus which 'dm' you currently use and what options are available to  before switching to another greeter*)

Comment: fyi:  I have 'Light GTK+ Greeter: settings' as an option on my 19.04 box, and I do like it's setup, however as my box no longer uses lightdm (it's 19.04 default of `sddm` now) the changes there will have no effect. This could be what you are experiencing - changes made not having effect because you're using another greeter (as I am). Your release (at a minimum) allows us to better recognize where you are & your issue.

Comment: If using `sddm` - the official lubuntu manual provides these clues (https://manual.lubuntu.me/3/3.1/3.1.9/sddm_configuration.html) though my sddm.conf file appears to be `/etc/init/sddm.conf`  (ie. `sddm` is default for 18.10 & 19.04)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using LUbuntu 19.10 as I am then the sddm search lead me to 
"https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?t=138785". Cobber said that he changed this "/usr/share/sddm/themes/breeze/theme.conf" file.

Going into my own settings I found this folder "/usr/share/sddm/themes/lubuntu
" Where I had a file called "wall.png" and a file "them.conf" with the command "background=wall.png". I just changed the picture to another one that I called wall.png and it used the new picture as my background.

Hope this helps. Lubuntu 19.04 probably will work the same since they are practically the same but I did not actually test it.